# Can I upgrade SDK from 29 to 30 in my tablet

Tags: android, sdk

The system on my tablet is android 10 and SDK 29.
I want to install an app (sdk 30). Google play prevents even the download of the app.
I searched for the system updates but I don't find on my tablet. So that, I want to know if it is possible to upgrade only the SDK in my tablet from 29 to 30 and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It is not possible. Mostly updates are provided by your phone manufacturers(like Samsung, Oppo, Vivo, etc.)
If your phone is quite new(in terms of processor, ram, storage) you will definitely get an update, but if it's not then there is no way which may be feasible for you.
However, if you have a Pixel device you can opt for Android SDK beta and try it out!
My personal suggestion is to build for minimum SDK as 24 as many devices today also have older versions of android installed and thus, you can reach a much larger audience(caveat is that you don't have features that require min SDK to be 30).